# Remove everything after fifth and including / (update table)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In a column called `sites` I have data like:

```
http://mysharepoint/site1/test/test2

http://mysharepoint/site1/test

http://mysharepoint/site3/test/test4/test432

http://mysharepoint/site1/test
```

I need to update the table with the removal of the fifth `/` and everything after.
The length of the sitename can vary, else I would easily fixed this via excel and imported it again.

I tried a huge ammount of right and left ways with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as follows:

```
UPDATE yourTable SET sites=(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/', sites, 
                                      CHARINDEX('/', sites,
                                      CHARINDEX('/', sites,
                                      CHARINDEX('/', sites,
                                      CHARINDEX('/', sites)+1)+1)+1)+1)-1 > 0
                                 THEN LEFT(sites,
                                           CHARINDEX('/', sites,
                                           CHARINDEX('/', sites,
                                           CHARINDEX('/', sites,
                                           CHARINDEX('/', sites,
                                           CHARINDEX('/', sites)+1)+1)+1)+1)-1
                                          ) 
                                 ELSE sites END)
```

The `CASE WHEN` is required if theres no `/` present.

[**Demo Link**](http://rextester.com/XSZ85637)

Comment: Before I test your suggestion, will it remove the fifth / and everything after, no matter the lenght on the sitename before? As I can said it can vary by alot.

Edit: Took a backup and it ran it, seems very legit.

Comment: @Gatewarden: Added a Demo Link